# Converting Date into a mm/yy/dd at xx:xx AM/PM <time zone> in javascript

Tags: javascript

I have an epoch time. I already converted into UTC date time. I want to convert it to as follows.

```
<div class="jb-ta-senton-section">Sent on:<span id="sentTime"></span></div>

var epochTime = values.tenderDetails.tenderCreated;
var utcTime = new Date(epochTime);
console.log(utcTime);
return utcTime;
```

This returns a date that is displayed in screen as

> "Sent on: Tue May 31 2016 13:29:29 GMT-0500 (Central Daylight Time)".

I want to convert it to

> "Sent on: 5/31/2016 at 1:29 PM CST"

Comment: Sent On is your static text. After that if you want to ao anything with timestamps you can use moment.js which is being used as "the de facto standard" for playing with timestamps

Comment: Use `utcTime.getMonth()` and so on. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date

Comment: Thanks for the replies. I should've mention I am trying to convert the time in an Ext.js application. I used Ext.Date.format.

Ext.Date.format(utcTime, 'm/d/y , H:i'). Now I need to figure out to convert the time into a 12 hour format with a time zone.

Comment: Thank you for the replies and apologies for the late reply. I got the solution after seeing your replies. Thank you so much